# solutions to systems of linear equations and RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

following an example from here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix

Given $A=\pmatrix{1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;2 \\ 1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;1 \\ 2\;\;\;2 \;\;\;2}, X=\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}, B=\pmatrix{3\\1\\2}$ forming the linear system:
$ AX=B$

Performing Gaussian elimination (by hand), starting with this augmented matrix:

$\pmatrix{1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;2 \;\;\;3 \\ 1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;1 \\ 2\;\;\;2 \;\;\;2 \;\;\;2}$

After doing the following Row operations:

L3=L3-2L2

L2=L2-L1

L2=-L2

I stopped at this point:
$\pmatrix{1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;2 \;\;\;3 \\ 0 \;\;\;0 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;2 \\ 0\;\;\;0 \;\;\;0 \;\;\;0}$

it is clear that z=2
I decided to set x as a free variable and let x=t
then i get:
$\{x=t,y=1-t,z=2\}$

E.g, let $t=10$,
then $X_{10}= \pmatrix{10\\ 1-10 \\ 2} =\pmatrix{10 \\ -9 \\ 2}$

and $AX_{10}=\pmatrix{5\\ 3 \\ 6}$

The true RREF matrix is one step later with L1=L1-2L2:
$\pmatrix{\;\;\;\;1  \;\;\;\;\;\; 1 \;\;\;\;\; 0 \;\;\;\; -1 \\ 0 \;\;\;\;\; 0  \;\;\;\;\; 1  \;\;\;\;\; 2 \\ 0  \;\;\;\;\; 0  \;\;\;\;\; 0  \;\;\;\;\; 0}$

then again if x is the free param. we have this time: 
$\{x=t,y=-1-t,z=2\}$

(Please, note that i get this time $y=-1-t$ instead of $y=1-t$ before!)

E.g, let $t=10$,
then $X_{{10}_{RREF}}= \pmatrix{10\\ -1-10 \\ 2} =\pmatrix{10 \\ -11 \\ 2}$

and this time 'it works' as $AX_{{10}_{RREF}} = \pmatrix{3\\1\\2}$ which is indeed equal to $B$.

My question is: why does it make a difference to go to the FULL (or true?) RREF form? Why can't I stop 1 step before? It seems very strange, like if the system was 'wrong' at the point before L1=L1-2L2 ...
I am probably missing some fundamental point, but I hope that an answer to this will allow me to understand more about linear algebra (i know i could just say 'ok one must do the full RREF' but i m interested in the 'Why?')

Comment: You have $x+y+2z = 3$, which becomes $t+y + 4 = 3$, hence $y = -1-t$.

Comment: Your first solution with $y=1-t$ does NOT solve the first row.

Comment: oh thanks so much!! I forgot the the 2 was the z factor! of course its 2*2... thanks the fact that z=2 and this factor was the confusion..

Comment: i suddenly thought there was something special with RREF but no... of course you can stop whenever you want and the system should always be in a coherent form .. right?

Comment: You say, correctly, that when you multiply your "$X_{10}$" by A you get $\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 3 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$.  But the problem was to find X such that AX was equal to $\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 3 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$.  That should have told you immediately that your "$X_{10}$" was wrong!

Comment: [...] was to find X such that AX equal to $\begin{bmatrix} 3\\1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ you mean haha not only i am making typos lol